# K8S on Docker Desktop cannot pull private repo - pull access denied

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerhub

I have logged in to the Docker hub using the CLI command: docker login. Entered username and password and I can pull and push images to Docker hub.

However, my K8S can't. I am trying to apply a deployment that should pull those images into its pods but I got the following error when running `kubectl describe pod POD_NAME`:

```
  Warning  Failed     9s    kubelet            Failed to pull image "myprivate/repo:tag": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for myprivate/repo, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

How to make the docker run in the pods to also be logged to the docker hub as well as doing it from my terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create "image pull secret" and define on your deployment. Here is how you can do https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/